# Hi, i have issues with positioning in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I leave these images here and now I explain.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Good. Image 1 represents what I am doing, it is a flexbox container with 4 items inside that when pressing the arrow they move from 2 to 2, leaving the first 2 behind.

First problem: (image 2) As you can see in image 2, only the last box (after doing all the scroll to the right and showing all the elements) remains stuck at the end of the container without responding to margins or right paddings ( The margin / padding top / left / bottom works perfectly!) Therefore, with this problem, I cannot maintain the aspect ratio with respect to the rest of the items.

Second problem: (image 3) In image 3 I am trying to do something, and it is that a container (.card (which are the elements that are inside the red container (#cards)) when hovering over it changes its height and stand out above the red to see the sizes, add to cart button..etc.

I leave a clearer example:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

In image 5 I put the mouse over the product.

Here is the code, I hope you can help me and tell me that I am missing and failing.

Thanks a lot!!

HTML: (I leave an example with static images)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<script src="{{ asset('js/home-scroll-controllers.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/add-cart.js') }}" defer></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            @if(session('message'))
            {{session('message')}}
            @endif
            <br/>
            <h1>Novedades</h1>
            <div id='cards'>
                @foreach($products_limit as $product)
                <div id="card-{{$product->id}}" class="card" onmouseenter="mouseEnterMethod('{{$product->id}}')" onmouseleave="mouseLeaveMethod('{{$product->id}}')">
                    <img id="image-{{$product->id}}" class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c3/8f/c7/c38fc74a67cf024cc0e07bef37c9baa5.jpg">

                    <h2>asdfg</h2>
                    <span>44€</span>
                    <a  class="addCart" id="addCart-{{$product->id}}">Añadir a la cesta</a>
                </div>


                @endforeach

            </div>
            <img id="slideLeft" src='{{ asset('img/previous.png') }}'/>
            <img id="slideRight" src='{{ asset('img/next.png') }}'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

CSS:

```
#cards{
    width: 85%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    overflow-x:  auto;
    overflow-y:  hidden;
    margin:0px auto;
    background: red;
    height: 320px;
}

#cards {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* For Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* For Internet Explorer and Edge */
}

#cards::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; /* For Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}


#cards .card{
    width: 22.9%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px#444;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#cards .card img{
    width: 280px;
    height: 240px;
    transition: all 300ms; 
}


#cards .card .addCart{
    opacity: 0;
    width: 85%;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background:#fff;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 86%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}

#cards .card .addCart:hover{
    text-decoration: none
}



#cards .card h2{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#cards .card span{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#slideLeft{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#slideRight{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function mouseEnterMethod(id) {

    let card = document.querySelector('#card-' + id);
    let addCart = document.querySelector('#addCart-' + id);

    card.style.height = "400px";
     card.style.position = "";
    addCart.style.opacity = "1";

}


function mouseLeaveMethod(id) {

    let cards = document.querySelector('#cards');
    let card = document.querySelector('#card-' + id);
    let addCart = document.querySelector('#addCart-' + id);
    let img = document.querySelector('#image-' + id);

    addCart.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function () {
        card.style.height = "";
    }, 100);
}
```

I hope you can help me!! thank you very much for reading this far

Comment: Use an external service like Codesandbox to show the output or show me the URL.

Comment: Hi @m4n0 It is something like this. The thing is, I don't know why the controls don't scroll the content of #cards. https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-tdd-fs2jp?file=/main.js  what I want is that when placing the cursor over a .card the entire content of it is displayed above #cards (as I showed in the example above)

Comment: You should try to implement the complete demo. Then people can help you better.

Comment: yes but i dont understand why controls doesnt work on codesanbox. Can u help me? thanks

Comment: That is not even your full code.